# Lead-acid battery + MOSFET-based spot welder keeps frying MOSFETs and drivers

Tags: transistors, mosfet, mosfet-driver, flyback

Here is [an imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JklOn.jpg) with relevant pictures and schematics.

Here is [a link to an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxVgOLQYaug&t=213s) on YouTube of one of the spot welders I'm trying to emulate.

I'm trying to build a spot welder following some tutorials on YouTube. I am going into my final year of school for EE, so I feel qualified to do this project, however, I haven't formally learned about MOSFETs in depth and am struggling.

I'm using 10 [IRF135B203](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf135s203.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015364c38ddf29b1) N-channel MOSFETs in parallel, each capable of handling >100 V and >130 A continuously. They were left over from a previous project. I purchased a MOSFET driver [TC4451](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/MCHPS05700_1-2520587.pdf) (capable of handling 12 A and 12 V to drive all 10 MOSFETs, and placed a 30 Ω resistor per MOSFET between the gate and the driver. I'm still learning, but from research it seems a resistor per gate is the right thing to do.

I'm triggering the gate driver with an ESP32 board on a standard 3.3 V GPIO pin, controlled via serial with my laptop. I have seen others using flyback diodes; I haven't purchased any yet as I saw others questioning their necessity.

Every time before I test I set the weld time to 3 s and run it dry while testing the MOSFETs with a multimeter, to make sure they open and then close. Then I set the time back to 10 ms and do an actual weld.

With all that being said I've burned about 10 MOSFETs trying to get this setup working. Every time I fry 2 or 3 MOSFETs on the first weld. I disassemble everything and test which ones died with a multimeter on the diode setting, and replace them. I have a screw clamping each MOSFET individually on both ends so they should all be making good contact.

At first I was worried about if I had bad connections or needed to switch the load on the source pin instead of the drain (seems unadvisable, but I gave it a try), but every time I make a weld I fry either MOSFETs, drivers, or both.

Maybe I have chosen the specific components incorrectly, but everything should work together, I think. I'm at my wits end but feel like I'm very close to getting this working, I just don't know what else to try.

Comment: Well, for one you've got a zillion MOSFETs in parallel... Unless they're perfectly matched, the ones that are fastest to turn on, or the ones with lowest RDS, will take the majority of the current.  So then one blows, the current load then is distributed between the other 9.  Another blows, etc...   This is a huge amount of current, 50-60A from a lead acid is easy.  Maybe 10x more depending the battery.  Have you put this on an oscilloscope yet?   The O-scope is an EE's 1st choice tool.

Comment: Here's a trick for new EE's.... App notes are your friend  :)     https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/application_note_en_20180726_AKX00067.pdf?did=59458

Comment: I don't see any bypass capacitors on the MOSFET driver. The data sheet should show recommended values. If the gate voltage oscillates, the devices will pass through their linear region where they will dissipate a lot of power. Also, are you measuring the actual current being drawn?

Comment: Please embed the schematic and images in the post. What's your gate resistor values?

Answer (score 5):

Since the load is essentially a short, the MOSFETs must switch fast to spend as little time as possible in the region between ON and OFF where RdsON is high.

Using the manufacturer's spice model, driven with 12V and a 30R gate resistor, I get about 1µs before gate voltage reaches 10V, and a total switching dissipation energy of 95µJ per MOSFET which is fine, switching time is not the problem.

However on the pictures I see rather long wires, and the MOSFET driver is powered directly from 12V with no visible decoupling capacitor.

Hypothesis 1: would be that as the MOSFETs turn on, battery voltage will drop due to the huge current. This will also drop the supply voltage of the MOSFET driver, and therefore the MOSFET gate voltage, perhaps to a point the gate voltage becomes too low to get the low RdsON you need.

Hypothesis 2: the gate driver bringing down its local VCC when switching due to lack of decoupling capacitor and long wires. Perhaps it could oscillate.

Hypothesis 3: MOSFETs oscillation due to long gate wire inductance.

Hypothesis 4: some of the SMD resistors have cracked and only a few are still functional, leaving too few MOSFETs ON, so they take too much current and burn.

[image]

All have the same fix: remove the gate resistor assembly and put a bit of perfboard below the MOSFETs, then solder SMD gate resistors on this board. This will prevent them from cracking. Put the driver on the same board, with short wires to gates and source bar.

[image]

Add local decoupling capacitance, and a diode to prevent voltage drop on the battery to bring down the driver's local supply.

You need enough capacitance to power the driver while the battery voltage drops, so at least a few hundred µF. It needs very low ESR to deliver the large gate current spike which should be around 4A. Total gate capacitance should be on the order of 100nF, so the decoupling cap should be much larger than that to avoid voltage drop. I'd use perhaps 2-3x 10µF 25V X7R SMD MLCCs for the initial high current spike, plus whatever electrolytic you have lying around to keep the driver powered (140µA) after switching, maybe a few hundred µF. Then a resistor to limit charging current.

If my hypothesis is correct this should work. In case it doesn't, before welding, you can put scope probes, one channel on the battery voltage and one channel on the MOSFET gates. Ground on the MOSFET source bar. Trigger on gate voltage, say 1V rising, record for the length of the pulse. Test the scope setup without actual welding. Then do a weld. If you see the battery voltage drop significantly but the added capacitors keep the gate voltage to a healthy 11V and nothing blows then it's fixed. If you see oscillations, then it needs more work.

A big freewheeling diode could perhaps help. I'm not really worried about the MOSFETs, they will avalanche, but the voltage spike at turn-off could harm the driver.

Extra:

For switching, MOSFETs care about Vgs, so the driver ground should be connected to the source of the FETs. Since you use one driver, IMO the best spot would be in the center of the row of FETs to get shortest gate wires, then connect its ground to the source bar at this point. Voltage drop along the bar should be minimal anyway

The MOSFET driver only cares about voltage between its input pin and its ground pin. So ESP32 ground should be wired to driver ground (not battery ground). Otherwise voltage between these two grounds can cause false triggering. Wires should be short and twisted to minimize induction from the high current loop. The worst case would be a negative spike on driver input when the high current turns on, which would turn the driver off, then repeat, oscillate, and MOSFETs blow.

[image]

Basically the bottom schematic (star grounding) puts the voltage across the impedance of the ground busbar and connections in series with the FET source, so the driver is not referenced to the FET source, which can create problems (oscillations, etc). Driver ground should go to FET source as per top schematic. ESP32 ground should go to driver ground too, otherwise the reference voltage of the input signal will change during switching.

Comment: Gerat answer! One question: Would you place the GND-Connection of the driver as close as possible to the battery to keep the voltage drop of the return line from disturbing the driver or close to the MOSFET drain so the gate voltage does not suffer from voltage drop across the GND return line? BTW: I think it's Hypothesis 1 :)

Comment: For switching, MOSFETs care about Vgs, so the driver ground should be connected to the source of the FETs. Since you use one driver, IMO the best spot would be in the center of the row of FETs to get shortest gate wires, then connect its ground to the source bar at this point. Voltage drop along the bar should be minimal anyway.

Comment: By the way, aluminium oxide is an excellent insulator, so if you used aluminium bars, contact with the FET drain tabs, battery, etc, may not be that good. If the holes are tapped that will remove the oxide and the screws will make good contact ; if you did not and simply used bolts and nuts, perhaps serrated washers would work best.

Comment: The MOSFET driver only cares about voltage between its input pin and its ground pin. So ESP32 ground should be wired to driver ground (not battery ground). Otherwise voltage between these two grounds can cause false triggering. Wires should be short and twisted to minimize induction from the high current loop. The worst case would be a negative spike on driver input when the high current turns on, which would turn the driver off, then repeat, oscillate, and MOSFETs blow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I will certainly be ordering some components to make the modifications you suggested. To you point on the driver/ microcontroller grounds, I have all grounds wired together, its not shown in the schematic but the ESP32 ground is connected to battery negative so everything is referencing the same potential. Are you saying that I should disconnect them and keep the driver on the esp32 ground? Wouldn't this affect the gate voltage relative to the source if the grounds are not the same?

Comment: Also the holes are not tapped, I wanted to solder everything but soldering busbars this big with oxides on them is hard. I do have an M3 tap but its cheap and I doubt it would last for 20 holes. Everything is pretty tight so I was hoping that would be good enough. Seems like others with making spot welders didn't have issues with the aluminum.

Comment: It's not possible to solder aluminium with electronics solder, so... nope. You could solder copper bars but given the size, you'd need to preheat it or something. Your M3 tap should work without trouble in aluminium, it's pretty soft. Basically, I'd say don't bother with tapping, screws are fine, maybe scrape off the oxide with sandpaper then wipe it to remove bits of sand left... I've added more stuff in the answer

Comment: You can also use "NoAlOx" https://www.idealind.com/us/en/shop/catalog/product/view/id/5536/s/noalox/ compound on the aluminum to keep it from oxidizing. And you can use self-tapping sheet metal screws to get good conductivity for the wire connections. Also, you can make bus bars from copper roofing foil or copper water pipe or tubing. That could be sandwiched to a thicker aluminum heat sink, using thermally conductive paste for good heat transfer.

Comment: Hello, so I've received the electronics I ordered and build a revised spot welder, but am not having much success. I haven't done a spot weld yet but I know it will not work as the mosfets are not switching, they have been in the open state since I did my first test, no matter if the signal on the input of the mosfet driver is high or low. I've probed all the voltages and everything seems to be in order except the driver output. I have two 1000uf caps and a diode for the flyback, and 2 22uf ceramic caps and 2 330uf caps for the driver supply. I also have the resistor and diode for the driver.

Comment: some new pictures: https://imgur.com/a/KNwGXCw I also changed the gate resistors to 10 ohm and mounted them to a perfboard. Changed the mosfets to these: TK4R3E06PL, for cost. Shortened the driver wire a lot also.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting them on the same heatsink and placing maybe a 10 Ω resistor in the gate. The source and drain should have minimal resistance between them. MOSFETs have a positive temperature coefficient and as they get warmer their resistance goes up, this forces the others to pick up the slack. There is a mode where they will go negative, but it is hard to put them in that mode.

If you check several MOSFET manufacturers have application notes explaining this. I have done this, it does work very well. Years ago, Motorola made a MOSFET a 10N10M which was a current mirror MOSFET. That would be paralleled with another, and you could measure circuit current without loss. It worked nicely but was temperature sensitive. I do not know if it is available anymore, but similar technology is used in some smart MOSFET devices.